# Rails: How to list database tables/objects using the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I was wondering if you could list/examine what databases/objects are available to you in the Rails console. I know you can see them using other tools, I am just curious.
Thanks.

Comment: that's what script/dbconsole is for though

Comment: Yes, that drops you into mysql (or whatever). For some stranger reason I want to list columns/tables etc from regular console. I am thinking that it might require custom made ruby methods to do such a thing.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

You are probably seeking:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns('projects').map(&:name)
```

You should probably wrap them in shorter syntax inside your `.irbrc`.

Comment: Thanks, the first one works like I want. But the second one doesn't - hunted for something similar but no luck.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns("foos") should also work, but it returns column objects, .map{|c| [c.name, c.type] } on the end fixes that.

Comment: `table_structure` seems to be specific to the sqlite adapter.

Comment: For Rails4 use Model.column_names to list table columns

Comment: Also in Rails 4, you can just use _ModelName_ to get a list of the columns and their data types.

Comment: I found this query useful as well: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('select * from <table>')

Answer (score 33):

I hope my late answer can be of some help.
This will go to rails database console.

```
rails db
```

pretty print your query output

```
.headers on
.mode columns
(turn headers on and show database data in column mode )
```

Show the tables

```
.table
```

'.help' to see help.
Or use SQL statements like 'Select * from cars'

Comment: 'rails dbconsole' puts you in the command line interpreter (CLI) of whatever database engine you're using... the above are SQLite commands... Postgres, for example, would use '\dt' to list tables...

Comment: is there a way to ensure that every time you don't have to apply .headers on and .more columns when running rails db

Answer (score 9):

To get a list of all model classes, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses` e.g.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.map { |cl| cl.name }
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.find { |cl| cl.name == "Foo" }
```

Comment: Also: `ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map(&:name)`

Comment: In development you also need `Rails.application.eager_load!` before. Also it will not list all tables, for example it miss ActiveStorage tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rails dbconsole` to view the database that your rails application is using. It's alternative answer `rails db`. Both commands will direct you the command line interface and will allow you to use that database query syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

Then

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
```

To return a list of models/tables

Answer (score -3):

Its a start, it can list:

```
models = Dir.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models").entries
```

Looking some more...

Comment: by doing this you just list models files what if tables are exists in db and do not have model fild in the models dir !!