# Show data in table from Rails Console for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I find something like this: [Rails: How to list database tables/objects using the Rails console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098131/list-databases-objects-using-rails-console)

This line is fine:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

and returns all tables

but

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_structure("users")
```

generate error:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_structure("projects")
```

I think that

```
table_structure
```

is not Postgres method.

How can I list all data from the table in Rails console for Postgres database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get this information from postgres directly from the command line

```
psql your_development_database -c "\d"
-- lists all database tables

psql your_development_database -c "\d users"
-- lists all columns for a table; 'users' in this case
```

If you want to look at Model attributes in the rails console

```
User.new
User.new.inspect

# or install the awesome_print gem for better output
ap User.new
```

Comment: don't forget: \q to exit the psql console. just saved you a search ;)

Comment: @grooble - the above is using the `-c` option so it executes the command but does not enter an interactive `psql` session, no need to `\q` in that case