# How to show active-record tables and their columns on the CLI?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, terminal, rails-activerecord

I am new to active-record and I am doing table migrations. I want to see tables that I have migrated with their corresponding column names on the terminal. Does anyone know the command to do this?

Let say I have 2 tables cats and dogs, is there a command that would show something like this in my CLI?

```
dogs
---------
name 
breed
age

cats 
---------
name
breed
age
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you can get this information about your database out but this should work from a `rails console`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  next unless ActiveRecord.const_defined?(table.classify) && !table.match(/schema_migrations/)
  puts table.classify.to_s
  puts '-----'
  puts table.classify.constantize.column_names
  puts
  puts
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are probably seeking:
>
> `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`
>
> and
>
> `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_structure("projects")`

Ref [Rails: How to list database tables/objects using the Rails console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098131/rails-how-to-list-database-tables-objects-using-the-rails-console)